# How to use GitHub repo with a solution with many projects

Tags: c#, github

I have a visual studio solution that has 15 projects in it. I am new to GitHub so I am trying to figure out how I should put this solution in a repository. In the solution, there is a core project that is the core application, then each additional project is a 'module'.

I could upload it all as one, but the project files all together are > 200MB. Also, most work is done on each project individually. So, this leads me to think I should upload each one separately. The only thing is that each of the modules work together and some have dependencies on others...so this would make it difficult to make sure everyone has the newest code, right?

Maybe I am over thinking this, but could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I'm unclear how this is related to GitHub?  Just organize your solution how you'd like and put it up on GitHub.

Comment: If you want to "authorize" per project on GitHub, you'll have to have each csproj in it's own repo--which would be a nightmare to consolidate and build, IMO

Comment: Well I saw something about submodules in Git so I was wondering it that could be an option, but I am not familiar with that at all. It looks like the most logical solution will be just to have it all in one repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the different projects depend on each other and you want to make sure you have the updated code than in my opinion it's easier to just have it all in the same place.

Another thing I can think about is having the Core projects in nuget packages, but if the code is changing all the time then that's probably not really a desired solution.

Comment: The core code shouldn't change all that much, but to make sure everything is in sync, it may just make sense to just have it all in the same repo. I suppose the only thing I can think of that would be an issue, is that if someone wanted to just branch one of the 'modules' they'd have to branch the whole project...I would think that could lead to some issues if some of the branches also edited core code, right?

Comment: Yea that's the problem. Where I work we also got a huge project with modules and core projects and we have everything in one git repository. I only work on one module but I need to code in several projects. We have some extensions things and the like in nuget packages, but those are rarely changed.